# Resigning Modal View with 2 different segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

Currently I have a UIBarButton that says Done in ViewController 2. I present ViewController2 from ViewController 1 modally through a segue defined in Storyboard. I also have another ViewController3 which presents ViewController2 modally as well.

The Question: How can I define two different segues to resign ViewController2 modally to either VC1 or VC3?

After further research, it seems that defining a unwindToViewController in VC1 and VC3 would be the best way to go. However, is there a way to call an IBAction before the modal view unwinds?

```
@implementation RedViewController

- (IBAction)unwindToRed:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
}

@end
```

**ModalView .m**

```
-(IBAction)actionBeforeUnwinding:(id)sender {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just dismissing itself from presentingViewController?

```
- (IBAction)unwindToRed:(id)sender
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I want to undwind from the modalview though. This will present VC1 or VC3 modally

Comment: U mean you just want to dismiss it, and go to the viewController, which presented it? If so then simply [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: is deprecated in ios 6, but yes that's the functionality that I was looking for!

Comment: yeah, new method I guess, is just dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, should work

Comment: OK cool. And also, is there a way to have a method triggered in the rootviewcontroller (the destination viewcontroller from modalviewcontrolelr)?

Comment: You want to send a message to the viewController which presented modalViewController? When?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34014/discussion-between-hurden-and-grasp)